# asp net 6 nginx docker connection refused

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nginx

I have a VM with Ubuntu and Docker.

I have two containers (ASP .NET 6 app and nginx server)

My docker compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - myapp
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    restart: always
      
  myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    image: <...>
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - logs:/mnt/logs
      - data:/mnt/data

volumes:
    logs:
    data:
```

when i try to connect to port 80 it says "connection refused".

If I try it with default nginx config, then default nginx page is opened.

if I open port 5000 for myapp, then i can access it on this port.

nginx config:

```
server {
        listen: 80;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://myapp:5000;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your .NET app listens on port 5000? Usually, .NET apps listen on port 80.

Comment: 1. container list: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/9VUcM2AgIUBLTQ
2. app works on 5000 port if i open it in docker compose file
3. In the Dockerfile i set it to 5000: `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved: my config file mount was incorrect.

Correct version:

```
<...>
volumes:
    - nginx-config:/etc/nginx/conf.d

<...>
volumes:
    logs:
    data:
    nginx-config:
```

and now i can change file `/var/lib/docker/volumes/coi_nginx-config/_data/default.conf`